# How to disable background modes in xcode so you can build to the device?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, uibackgroundmode, ios-background-mode

I enabled Background Mode to try it out and now its preventing my app from building to a device. I am trying to disable background mode because quite frankly its messing up my builds and preventing me from running the app. I tried building on the simulator and a real device and neither are working. I have removed the background capabilities and also removed the keys from my info.plist. Does anyone know how to get rid of the error shown in the screenshot so I can just run my app again?

[See Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYcti.png)

[image]

[See Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlSPU.png)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [what kinds of questions can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, edit your question so that we may help.  Specifically, you need to include all relevant code and/or error messages **within the body of the question** so that if the **link** disappears, the question will still be valid and useful. The easier you make it for us to know the question, the better your chances of receiving an answer. Cheers!

Comment: Enabling (or disabling) background modes has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: What is the issue? When I add background mode the app launches.